# How does CSS works under the hood?

Tags: css

I would like to know how css works under the hood.
Whether the html that gets download will be interpreted before CSS's interpretation or after?
Or it will apply as soon as DOM has been constructed by the browser. Please give me detailed clarification on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An HTML page is parsed the order it is built. if the CSS is parsed already, the elements that have styles in that parsed CSS will get styled immediately when they are laid in the page. That's why CSS is preferrably loaded in the `<head>` - before the tags in the body get a chance of being painted to the page.

if you load the CSS late, then elements will be shown in their "unstyled form" until their styles (it any) are parsed. this is what's known as "FUOC" or "Flash Of Unstyled Content"

Answer (score 0):

This page provides many details about that.

- http://www.westciv.com/style_master/academy/css_tutorial/introduction/how_they_work.html
- http://www.westciv.com/style_master/academy/css_tutorial/introduction/what_are_ss.html